# NumberRange validator not working for negative numbers

Tags: validation, flask, wtforms

I have created a class in python called EntryForm and want to validate the inputs for somebody's income to be a number greater than 0, and am using Flask-wtf / wtforms for the validation. When I use the code below, the InputRequired() works as expected, but the NumberRange does not.  Negative numbers, or not numeric inputs, do not result in an error.

```
class EntryForm(FlaskForm):
    income = IntegerField('Income', validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, message='Must enter a number greater than 0')])
```

Here is calling the class

```
form = EntryForm()
    if form.is_submitted():
        data = request.form
        user_income = int(data.get('income'))


This is the html portion
<form action="/" method="POST">
                <p>
                    {{form.hidden_tag() }}
                    {{form.income.label}}
                    {{form.income(size=20)}}
                    {% for error in form.income.errors %}
                        {{error}}
                    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke `validate_on_submit` rather then `is_submitted`

```py
form = EntryForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    data = request.form
    user_income = int(data.get('income'))
    ...
    return 
return render('your_template_name.html', form=form)
```